# To show a set is open

Tags: general-topology

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}$ be open

define $B = \lbrace{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \in A} \rbrace$

Show that $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 2):

[The product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is the coarsest topology that makes the projections continuous.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition)

Now check that $B$ is the preimage of $A$ under one of these projections.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x$, then $f^{-1}(A)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\;|\; f(x,y)=x\in A\}=B$ hence $B$ is the preimage of an open set by the continuous projection map $f$, so $B$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of open set. Try to make an open ball around any point in B, and use the definition of B and the fact that $A\in\mathbb{R}$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = (a,b) \in B$. Let $r>0$ be such that if $|x-a| < r$ then $x \in A$. Then say $(c,d) \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $||(a,b) - (c,d)||_1 < r$. Of course all norms generate the same topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is why I used the $1$-norm.

Then $|a-c| + |b-d| < r$ so $|a-c| < r$ so $c \in A$. Hence, $(c,d) \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is open, for any $x \in A$ there exists $r>0$ such that the open ball of radius $r$, centered at $x$, belongs to $A$. An open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of this same radius $r$, centered at $(x,y) \in B$, will belong to $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that a base of the product topology are sets of the form $X\times Y$, for open sets $X$ and $Y$. Now since $\mathbb R$ and $A$ are open, so is $B=A\times \mathbb R$.